# How to extract DateTime from German Sentences?

Tags: c#, date, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a chatbot with the Microsoft Bot Framework with LUIS (language understanding). Since the provided datetime entity is not sufficient I am currently struggeling with the best way how to detect dates in German. Dates can be in the format `'01.01.2019'` but also as relative date like `'nächste Woche'` (next week), `'morgen'` (tomorrow), `'am Montag'` (on Monday), etc.

Since a new DateTime Entity (v2) is already available for some languages in LUIS I tried to integrate the library https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text which is also used for the LUIS DateTimeV2 Entity within my code. Even though this is an improvement to the provided date from LUIS the result is still not sufficient. I already implemented some kind of backup logic but I am wondering if anybody knows a good library for German date extraction.

Comment: Why not try using [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) for every query you want to find.

Comment: I already have basic pattern matching but there are a number of cases that have to be considered. So before reinventing the wheel I wanted to ask if someone already has done this.

Comment: Why not contribute to the OSS that you have identified as better but not perfect (https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text)? It says that they currently have limited German support - I bet they would welcome your help in improving it.

Comment: Or a question on their Git Hub support page acknowledging the gap in functionality and asking for guidance might help you tackle your own implementation. If you are able to articulately define what is lacking they might value your feedback.

Comment: To add to TheFastCat's response, you could contribute directly, ask for guidance, or also simply open an issue on specific scenarios that are not covered in the https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/issues repo. The dev team will prioritize implementation on the feature based on community feedback and balance w/other tickets they have on their plate

Comment: The last update improved the German language support a lot so that it is (in most cases) sufficient for me at the moment. Thanks a lot for all the replies!